# ProcessBuilder is not able to find the file of a given command

Tags: java, windows, processbuilder

I am building a CLI tool that is running the following Maven command

```
mvn archetype:generate -B -DarchetypeGroupId=me.pablo -DarchetypeArtifactId=fleeti-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.0 -Dversion=1.0 -DgroupId=me.pablo -Dpackage=me.pablo -Dname=Test -DartifactId=test
```

it's supposed to run this command in the following directory

```
C:\Users\35356\Desktop\Test
```

Now, I created my own utility class to run the commands I need using **ProcessBuilder**:

```
package me.pablo.processes;

import me.pablo.FleetiMessage;
import me.pablo.FleetiMessageType;
import me.pablo.commands.Command;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class FleetiProcess
{
    private List<Command> commands;
    private List<Process> allProcesses;

    public FleetiProcess(final List<Command> commands) {
        this.commands = commands;
        this.allProcesses = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void execute() {
       runProcess();
    }

    public void executeAsync(final int delayInSeconds) {
        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().schedule(this::runProcess, delayInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public void execute(final int delayInSeconds) {
        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().schedule(this::stopFleetiProcess, delayInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        runProcess();
    }

    public void stopFleetiProcess() {
        allProcesses.forEach(Process::destroyForcibly);
    }

    private void runProcess() {
        commands.forEach(command -> {
            // Debug messages
            System.out.println("Raw command is \n" + command.getRawCommand());
            System.out.println("Split command is \n" + Arrays.toString(command.getRawCommand().split(" ")));
            System.out.println("Target file exist: \n" + new File(command.getPath()).exists());

            final ProcessBuilder commandBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
            commandBuilder.command(command.getRawCommand().split(" "));
            commandBuilder.directory(new File(command.getPath()));
            try {
                final Process commandProcess = commandBuilder.start();
                final StreamGobbler streamGobbler = new StreamGobbler(commandProcess.getInputStream(), System.out::println);
                Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(streamGobbler);
                allProcesses.add(commandProcess);

                int exitVal = commandProcess.waitFor();
                if (exitVal == 0) {
                    FleetiMessage.printMessage(
                            new FleetiMessage(FleetiMessageType.SUCCESS, "Successfully ran process for " + command.getRawCommand()));
                } else {
                    FleetiMessage.printMessage(
                            new FleetiMessage(FleetiMessageType.ERROR, "Could not run process for command " + command.getRawCommand()));
                }
            } catch (final IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    private static class StreamGobbler implements Runnable {
        private InputStream inputStream;
        private Consumer<String> consumer;

        StreamGobbler(InputStream inputStream, Consumer<String> consumer) {
            this.inputStream = inputStream;
            this.consumer = consumer;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream)).lines()
                    .forEach(consumer);
        }
    }
}
```

Every time I run this code, I run into the same error:

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mvn" (in directory "C:\Users\35356\Desktop\Test"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

I've researched this problem, and I've tried the suggested solutions: trying to pass the command in the ProcessBuilder constructor, running the command as a single String, and making sure the file actually exists.

However, I know for a fact that the file exists. This is the complete console output:

```
Raw command is
mvn archetype:generate -B -DarchetypeGroupId=me.pablo -DarchetypeArtifactId=fleeti-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=1.0 -Dversion=1.0 -DgroupId=me.pablo -Dpackage=me.pablo -Dname=Test -DartifactId=test
Split command is
[mvn, archetype:generate, -B, -DarchetypeGroupId=me.pablo, -DarchetypeArtifactId=fleeti-archetype, -DarchetypeVersion=1.0, -Dversion=1.0, -DgroupId=me.pablo, -Dpackage=me.pablo, -Dname=Test, -DartifactId=test]
Target file exist:
true
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mvn" (in directory "C:\Users\35356\Desktop\Test"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at me.pablo.processes.FleetiProcess.lambda$runProcess$0(FleetiProcess.java:53)
        at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Unknown Source)
        at me.pablo.processes.FleetiProcess.runProcess(FleetiProcess.java:43)
        at me.pablo.processes.FleetiProcess.execute(FleetiProcess.java:26)
        at me.pablo.commands.FleetiCreateAppCommand.run(FleetiCreateAppCommand.java:89)
        at picocli.CommandLine.executeUserObject(CommandLine.java:1729)
        at picocli.CommandLine.access$900(CommandLine.java:145)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2101)
        at picocli.CommandLine$RunLast.handle(CommandLine.java:2068)
        at picocli.CommandLine$AbstractParseResultHandler.execute(CommandLine.java:1935)
        at picocli.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:1864)
        at me.pablo.FleetiCLI.main(FleetiCLI.java:19)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
        ... 14 more
```

I ran this code in MacOS and worked perfectly. I am only having this issue when running on a Windows. Does anyone know what could be the issue?

Comment: try running `mvn -v` command from command line and check whether maven is installed in the machine. Error looks like maven is not installed/ not set in path variable.

Comment: I've tried to run the entire command on cmd and it works perfectly to generate the maven project.Also, that's how I package this code into a jar, so I know that Maven is working. @Binu

Comment: Are you running the jar from the same system or another system?

Comment: @Binu I build the jar in the same system and run it there

Comment: Thanks for the update. Try `Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);`

Comment: The code you posted is not a [mcve]. I suggest you [edit] your question and post code that I can copy and run on my machine.

Comment: @Binu that didn't work